# Does the duty free laptop come under 25K entitlement? (India customs)

Tags: customs-and-immigration, duty-free

I will be traveling to the US shortly from India and will be returning back. I am planning to purchase a laptop in the US and want to bring it to India. I read in the website of India customs where it says the following about "duty free" entitlement:

(ii)
Rs.25000/- (in value) if Stayed abroad for more than three days
(iii)
One Laptop computer (notebook computer) imported by a passenger (but not a member of the crew of a ship / aircraft)
Free, if the passenger is of the age of 18 years or above.

I want to know if the laptop mentioned in (iii) comes under (ii). 
To be more clear, can I bring items worth 25K Plus a laptop (worth whatever)?

Comment: Yes, the laptop allowance is "over and above" the personal allowance, so you're free to carry other items apart from the laptop.

Answer (score 3):

Personal items like laptops, iPads, phones, etc are fairly easy to get through Indian customs as long as you're bringing in a small number, and it doesn't seem like you're going to sell them to someone. Since most passengers generally have a laptop, a phone or two, and maybe a tablet, you can bring these without being stopped at customs.